# Fix the polygon self.intersection error using GDAL/Python

Tags: python, gdal

I want clip raster by shapefile based on GDAL/Python platform. However, it is not working.

The code:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal
shpfile="a.shp"
input_file="area.tiff"
output_file = "subarea.tiff"
outTile = gdal.Warp(output_file, input_file, cutlineDSName=shpfile, format="GTiff")
OutTile = None
```

The error:

> **Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 114.56538630983039 30.263472880169331**
> outTile = gdal.Warp(output_file, input_file, cutlineDSName=shpfile, format="GTiff")   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\base1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py",
> line 625, in Warp
> return wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(destNameOrDestDS, srcDSTab, opts, callback, callback_data)   File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\base1\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py",
> line 3410, in wrapper_GDALWarpDestName
> return _gdal.wrapper_GDALWarpDestName(*args)
>
> **ERROR 1: Cutline polygon is invalid.**

Comment: If you have QGIS, in the processing toolbox, either `buffer` the vector file by 0 or run `Fix Geometries` or run `Check validity` to find the issue(s) nd fix it manually.